# Phantomjs not running for complex methods used in Qunit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, automated-tests, qunit

I m using qunit for headless unit testing. After testing is done i convert the qunit results into junit-styled output .xml file to be used in Jenkins. The problem here when i m using the decode and encode functions and include this in the test process the phantom js is unable to generate any xml.
The encode decode functions i used are as follows :

```
     var encodeString = function(stringToEncode){
     return btoa(stringToEncode);
     var decodeString = function(stringToDecode){
     return atob(stringToDecode);
```

Is there any alternative to using these decode encode functions so that the phantomjs limitations can be encountered.Or any lead on any alternative for phantomjs which does the same job will be beneficial.